# div markup not on displayed page

Tags: php, wordpress

In the php file I have the following code

```
<div class="entry-meta">
    <?php echo theme_post_meta(); ?>
</div>
```

The function theme_post_meta calculates and returns html that has two spans.

```
<span class="posted-on">Posted 22 hours ago</span> / 
<span class="posted-in">News, Important</span>
```

However when the page is loaded in the browser the outer div is no longer there.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do php cancatenation as:

```
<?php echo '<div class="entry-meta">'.theme_post_meta().'</div>'; ?>
```

Comment: The same thing is happening. I also tried putting the div in the function, but still the same thing happened, no div.

Comment: Can you share screenshot?